# 2D animation is going reverse

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

hi guys i am working in 2d game . i have created 2d animation in animation tab . it is working fine with normal speed but when i increase the key frame rate or animation speed in animation state option. it starts going in the reverse direction my animation is from let say (-100 to 0 to 100) . i have tried all the interpolation options Euler angle quaternion and Eular angle (quaternion approximation ) in animation tab but nothing fixed my issue what is possibly i m doing wrong?

thanx in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by your "animation is from (-100 to 0 to 100)"?

Comment: in animation tab i am rotating game object from -100 degree to 100 degree at z-axis  counter Clockwise but when i try to increase the speed by any of the method mentioned above that i know it start to rotating clockwise in play mode

Comment: How many keyframe points do you have on the animation curve? Did you tried to make the animation more discrete in order to set more specific way for the transform to change (in other words - to add few keyframes more between the start and end points)?

Comment: Yeah i solved the problem just by adding more key frames in between starting and ending point